# CustomChangeMove in chained planning entities throws IllegalStateException (Optaplanner)

Tags: java, optaplanner

I want to do a custom change move to chained planning entities.
When certain conditions are met suppose I want to move `E` such that it comes after `B` as in the example below.

`A <- B <- C` and `D <- E <- F` become `A <- C` and `D <- B <- E <-F`

To achieve this I implemented a `CustomChangeMove`:

```
public class CustomChangeMove extends AbstractMove<VehicleRoutingSolution> {

private Customer customer;
private Customer toPreviousStandstill;

private Customer oldTrailingEntity;
private Customer newTrailingEntity;


public CustomChangemove(Customer customer, Customer toPreviousStandstill, Customer oldTrailingEntity, Customer newTrailingEntity) {
    this.customer = customer;
    this.toPreviousStandstill = toPreviousStandstill;
    this.oldTrailingEntity = oldTrailingEntity;
    this.newTrailingEntity = newTrailingEntity;
}

@Override
protected void doMoveOnGenuineVariables(ScoreDirector<VehicleRoutingSolution> scoreDirector) {
    Standstill oldPreviousStandstill = customer.getPreviousStandstill();

    scoreDirector.beforeVariableChanged(customer, "previousStandstill" );
    //fix old chain
    oldTrailingEntity.setPreviousStandstill(oldPreviousStandstill);
    // oldPreviousStandstill.setNextCustomer(oldTrailingEntity); // shadow variables are updated automatically

    // move object
    customer.setPreviousStandstill(toPreviousStandstill);
    // customer.setNextCustomer(newTrailingEntity); shadow variable

    //fix new chain
    toPreviousStandstill.setNextCustomer(customer);
    //    toPreviousStandstill.setNextCustomer(null);
    // newTrailingEntity.setPreviousStandstill(customer); // shadow variable


    scoreDirector.afterVariableChanged(customer, "previousStandstill");
}


 @Override
  public boolean isMoveDoable(ScoreDirector<VehicleRoutingSolution> scoreDirector) {
    return !Objects.equals(customer.getPreviousStandstill(), toPreviousStandstill) ||
        !Objects.equals(customer.getNextCustomer(), toPreviousStandstill);
  }
```

I would think that configuring the `previousStandstill`s and `nextCustomer`s this way would fix the chains but instead it is yielding me an `IllegalStateException`:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The entity (Customer [shipmentId=xx, vehicle=TimeWindowedVehicle [0]]) has a variable (previousStandstill) with value (Customer [xx, vehicle=TimeWindowedVehicle [0]]) which has a sourceVariableName variable (nextCustomer) with a value (Customer [shipmentId=xxxxx-1, vehicle=TimeWindowedVehicle [0]]) which is not null.
Verify the consistency of your input problem for that sourceVariableName variable.
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.domain.variable.inverserelation.SingletonInverseVariableListener.insert(SingletonInverseVariableListener.java:72) ~[optaplanner-core-7.0.0.Final.jar:7.0.0.Final]
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.domain.variable.inverserelation.SingletonInverseVariableListener.afterVariableChanged(SingletonInverseVariableListener.java:51) ~[optaplanner-core-7.0.0.Final.jar:7.0.0.Final]
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.domain.variable.listener.support.VariableListenerSupport.triggerVariableListenersInNotificationQueues(VariableListenerSupport.java:209) ~[optaplanner-core-7.0.0.Final.jar:7.0.0.Final]
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.score.director.AbstractScoreDirector.triggerVariableListeners(AbstractScoreDirector.java:228) ~[optaplanner-core-7.0.0.Final.jar:7.0.0.Final]
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.heuristic.move.AbstractMove.doMove(AbstractMove.java:38) ~[optaplanner-core-7.0.0.Final.jar:7.0.0.Final]
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.heuristic.move.AbstractMove.doMove(AbstractMove.java:27) ~[optaplanner-core-7.0.0.Final.jar:7.0.0.Final]
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.localsearch.decider.LocalSearchDecider.doMove(LocalSearchDecider.java:146) ~[optaplanner-core-7.0.0.Final.jar:7.0.0.Final]
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.localsearch.decider.LocalSearchDecider.decideNextStep(LocalSearchDecider.java:120) ~[optaplanner-core-7.0.0.Final.jar:7.0.0.Final]
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.localsearch.DefaultLocalSearchPhase.solve(DefaultLocalSearchPhase.java:70) ~[optaplanner-core-7.0.0.Final.jar:7.0.0.Final]
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.AbstractSolver.runPhases(AbstractSolver.java:87) ~[optaplanner-core-7.0.0.Final.jar:7.0.0.Final]
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolver.solve(DefaultSolver.java:163) ~[optaplanner-core-7.0.0.Final.jar:7.0.0.Final]
    at org.optaplanner.benchmark.impl.SubSingleBenchmarkRunner.call(SubSingleBenchmarkRunner.java:106) ~[optaplanner-benchmark-7.0.0.Final.jar:7.0.0.Final]
    at org.optaplanner.benchmark.impl.SubSingleBenchmarkRunner.call(SubSingleBenchmarkRunner.java:34) ~[optaplanner-benchmark-7.0.0.Final.jar:7.0.0.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
```

Another idea I have is to use the default `ChainedChangeMove`:

```
public class CustomChangeMoveFactory implements MoveListFactory<VehicleRoutingSolution> {

    @Override
    public List<ChainedChangeMove> createMoveList(VehicleRoutingSolution vrpSol) {
        List<ChainedChangeMove> moveList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Customer> customers = vrpSol.getCustomers();
        for (Customer c1 : customers) {
            for (Customer c2 : customers) {
                //if certain condition met add to movelist
                moveList.add(new ChainedChangeMove(c1, variableDescriptor ?, c2, c1.getNextCustomer(), c2.getNextCustomer()))
            }
        }
        return moveList;
    }

}
```

But for that I need a variableDescriptor that I don't have. 
Any ideas why my `CustomChangeMove` fails ?

**EDIT**
After quite some digging I feel that some sort of a circular reference occurs. I find that the method runs fine a few times before throwing an exception and the exception thrown is typically undoing a change that has been done before (due to how I generate these `CustomChangeMoves` this is not unthinkable).

I find that the exception is always thrown when the change is on the same chain. It occurs when the `customer` still has a `nextCustomer` (an `@InverseRelationShadowVariable`) that is not updated to `null` which normally it what it normally will be when the `previousStandstill` is updated.

So, when on the same chain `A <- B <- C <- D <- E`, the move will be such that to move `B` behind `E`: `A <- C <- D <- E <- B`. This will succeed. The following move will try to put `E` behind `B`: `A <- C <- D <- B <- E`, this is when the exception is thrown. Any ideas on how to deal with this are deeply appreciated.

Also, I don't understand why the move is even executed as `isMoveDoable` should prevent this from occurring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out I think. So far my implementation seems to work good and the issue seems to be occurring in `createUndoMove` code that I had not posted and which was wrong.

This full code seems to work (at least there are no exceptions being thrown):

```
public class CustomChangeMove extends AbstractMove<VehicleRoutingSolution> {

private Customer customer;
private Customer toPreviousStandstill;

private Customer oldTrailingEntity;
private Customer newTrailingEntity;


public CustomChangemove(Customer customer, Customer toPreviousStandstill, Customer oldTrailingEntity, Customer newTrailingEntity) {
    this.customer = customer;
    this.toPreviousStandstill = toPreviousStandstill;
    this.oldTrailingEntity = oldTrailingEntity;
    this.newTrailingEntity = newTrailingEntity;
}

@Override
protected void doMoveOnGenuineVariables(ScoreDirector<VehicleRoutingSolution> scoreDirector) {
Standstill oldPreviousStandstill = customer.getPreviousStandstill();

    // move object
    scoreDirector.beforeVariableChanged(customer, "previousStandstill" );
    customer.setPreviousStandstill(toPreviousStandstill);
    scoreDirector.afterVariableChanged(customer, "previousStandstill");

    //fix old chain
    if (oldTrailingEntity != null) {
      scoreDirector.beforeVariableChanged(oldTrailingEntity, "previousStandstill" );
      oldTrailingEntity.setPreviousStandstill(oldPreviousStandstill);
      scoreDirector.afterVariableChanged(oldTrailingEntity, "previousStandstill");
}

    //fix new chain
    if (newTrailingEntity != null) {
      scoreDirector.beforeVariableChanged(newTrailingEntity, "previousStandstill" );
      newTrailingEntity.setPreviousStandstill(customer);
      scoreDirector.afterVariableChanged(newTrailingEntity, "previousStandstill");
    }
}


 @Override
  public boolean isMoveDoable(ScoreDirector<VehicleRoutingSolution> scoreDirector) {
    return !Objects.equals(customer.getPreviousStandstill(), toPreviousStandstill) ||
        !Objects.equals(customer.getNextCustomer(), toPreviousStandstill);
  }

  @Override
  protected AbstractMove<VehicleRoutingSolution> createUndoMove(ScoreDirector<VehicleRoutingSolution> scoreDirector) {
    return new MultidropChangeMove(customer, customer.getPreviousStandstill(), newTrailingEntity, oldTrailingEntity);
  }

 @Override
  public Collection<?> getPlanningEntities() {
//    return Arrays.asList(customer, newTrailingEntity, oldTrailingEntity);
    return Collections.singletonList(customer);
  }

  @Override
  public Collection<?> getPlanningValues() {
//    return Arrays.asList(customer.getPreviousStandstill(), newTrailingEntity.getPreviousStandstill(), oldTrailingEntity.getPreviousStandstill());
    return Collections.singleton(customer.getPreviousStandstill());
  }
```

**EDIT**
This answer was also not right, the problem was solved coincidentally because it occured in some datasets while others were exempt.

The solution seems to be to not store the changing entities at construction time of the move as these are subjected to change later.

So a constructor of

```
public CustomChangemove(Customer customer, Customer toPreviousStandstill) {
    this.customer = customer;
    this.toPreviousStandstill = toPreviousStandstill;
}
```

is much better, `oldTrailingEntity` and `newTrailingEntity` can then be retrieved in `doMoveOnGenuinineVariables` as `customer.getNextCustomer()` or `toPreviousStandstill.getNextCustomer()`. This ensures the correct entities are retrieved and not some entity that has been changed.